# J2ME http get request

Tags: java, http, java-me

I was developing an application just for learning.

I have mobile 5230. I have developed a J2ME program that catches location data using GPS and send it to my server. Application was working fine from many days.

From today onwards, i am getting response code as 302 while the same request is giving 200 in browser.

Is there any setting i do need to check ?

UPDATION

I just have tried using the same code with emulator. It is working fine now. But it is not working on mobile. What should i test further ?

I have changed the application and tried to hit the same URL 2-3 times continuously. It is giving 302 for 1st time. But if i hit the same URL again then it is giving 200. But it is not updating on server side.

Comment: mobile 5230? DO you mean nokia 5230?

Comment: HttpConnection connection = null;
            int rc = 0;
            try {
                String urlTemp = url.getString();
                form.append("urlTemp" + urlTemp);
                connection = open(urlTemp);
                rc = connection.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println("Response code :: "+rc );
                form.append("Response code :: "+rc);
                connection.close();

Comment: Don't comment on this with code, add it to the question. And, updation isn't a word.